# Cast with multiple select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I need to select from multiple tables. in one of two tables i use cast. So my code is look like below:

```
insert into TEST (id,name) (SELECT (MAX(id) + 1), (select 'NEW-1-'+CAST((MAX(id) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) from test)
```

I get an error with incorrect syntax

Comment: What exactly am I looking at?   Are you trying to add the max (with an addition of 1) to something called new-1 into one string?  If that is all you are doing then you are missing some more code.  Do you wish to insert this new thing you have created?  Like, if max is 5, then the right side is 6 thus you would have 'New-1-6'.  Are you trying to insert this into a column?  If yes, then what is the name of the column and the table you are inserting it into?

Comment: I found what i was looking i need just a little detail to add. This is the code i was looking for: select 'New-1-'+CAST((MAX(ID) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)). the thing is what if i want to make multiple select? i tried this with syntax error. (SELECT (MAX(id) + 1), (select 'new-1-'+CAST((MAX(id) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10))  from test

Comment: Thank you for the information but next time try and edit your question and add it there.  Makes it easier for other users :) http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38463701/edit  I will right an answer that will hopefully help you.

Comment: I see this question is tagged Sql Server 2000. Sql Server 2000 is way past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading this server is job 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my understanding the piece of code you have...

```
 select 'New-1-'+CAST((MAX(ID) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

currently works?  But you are having trouble with...

```
 (SELECT (MAX(id) + 1), (select 'new-1-'+CAST((MAX(id) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) from test
```

So the issue you are having is with multiple selects.  You don't do multiple selects.  You can just keep typing them with commas in-between like so...

```
 SELECT (MAX(id) + 1), 'new-1-'+CAST((MAX(id) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) from test
```

This should be what you are looking for.  Please comment this answer if you have any questions and try to answer my follow up questions through your original question :)

Comment: Thank you Bro it works! Just only one last question. Is this really looks so easy for you? Cause i spend at least one day trying find an answer   ... : ) Thank you again!

Comment: @user6453809 haha don't worry eventually you will look back at this and think how much you've grown. I had a project last semester for college and I did a lot with sql. I didn't know much about it until then. It was quite the grind. This was the least of my worries :). You'll get there. Just by doing it it makes it easier. Nice thing about this field. Don't really have to study. Just need to do.